# How to get the 1st, 3rd and 5th element from an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is there a fast way to get the 1st, 3rd and 5th element from an array in Python like a[0,2,4]? Thanks.

Comment: like this `a[[0,2,4]]`

Answer (score 7):

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> import operator
>>> get135 = operator.itemgetter(0, 2, 4)
>>> get135(lst)
(1, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This module seems very nice!

Answer (score 5):

You could just do this, a simple method with no imports necessary:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
>>> [a[i] for i in (0, 2, 4)]
[1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

Slicing is the simplest way to do this. You'll want to slice it with [0:5:2].

```
>>> range(100)[0:5:2]
[0, 2, 4]
```

This is the equivalent of saying "Starting from element 0, up to (but not including) element 5, give me every 2nd element."

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing to get this.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
d = a[0:5:2]

print d
[1, 3, 5]
```

If you want to generalize to every other entry you would use

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

b = a[::2]

print b
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ,

Slicing operation on list.

```
 >>> a=[i for i in range(10)]
 >>> a[::2]
```

Ouput:

```
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps:

```
[list[0], list[2], list[4]]
```

Comment: The 5th element should be `list[4]`.